# if condition not working

Tags: c, if-statement

My aim is to take two strings and compare there ends if both of them ends with "ing","ed" or there ends do not match.It always says that strings do not match .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
int ised(char str[]);
int ising(char str[]);

int  main()
{
    char str1[30],str2[30];
    printf("Enter 1st string:\n");
    gets(str1);
    printf("Enter 2nd string:\n");
    gets(str2);
    if((ising(str1))||(ised(str1))||(ising(str2))||(ised(str2)))
    {
        if(ising(str1)&&ising(str2))
        {
            printf("Both strings end with ing");
        }
        else if(ised(str1)&&ised(str2))
        {
        printf("Both strings end with ed");
        }
        else
        printf("Both strings ending do not match");
    }
    else
    printf("One or both strings do not end with ing or ed.Program Quitting...");
    getch();
    return 0;
}
int ising(char str[])
{
    int len,flag=0;
    len=strlen(str);

        if (!(strncpy(&str[len-3],"ing",3)))
                flag=1;
        else
        flag=0; 
return flag;           
}
int ised(char str[])
{
    int len,flag=0;
    len=strlen(str);

        if( !(strncpy(&str[len-2],"ed",2)) )
                flag=1;
        else
        flag=0; 
return flag;           
}
```

Comment: which is the `if` that's misbehaving?

Comment: Off topic  :You have to name your functions in a better way.

Comment: @praveen:i really try my best for that but i dont get good names in my head.suggest me a good idea for that..i used this name because it means (ising == is a word ending with ing )

Comment: You might consider using the 'CamelCase' naming style. Each word in a function/variable name begins with a capital letter (sometimes except the first one). For example: `int myImportantVariable;` See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase

Comment: C is case sensivtive so there wont be a problem of same names of function(Str) and variable(str)?

Comment: Yes, that wont be a problem since `Str` and `str` are different thing to the compiler. However, i recommend you to name your functions and variables by different names (not just different capital letters).

Comment: @Fahad : Forget the problem. How would anyone reading your code know what does the function "ised" do. You can be more descriptive about the function name to indicate what they do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using `strncpy` which does string copying, if you want to compare strings, use `strncmp`.

See: [strncpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strncpy/)
and [strncmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strncmp/)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're using `strncpy` when you actually mean to use to `strcmp`.  You're trying to *compare* the strings, right?

Answer (score 1):

Use `strncmp`. And if you're slicing strings, don't forget the terminators.

Answer (score 0):

Would be nice to tell us where you're having problems, what you expect and the result you're currently getting.